# cygwin-x applications not starting

Tags: cygwin, cygwin-x

After installing Cygxin-X, X applications won't run:

```
$ xman
/usr/bin/xman.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ xcalc
/usr/bin/xcalc.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ xlogo
/usr/bin/xlogo.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmu-6.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But, I still am able to open windows through ssh

Here's the log from `startxwin`:

```
Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.15.0.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.3 ETHAN-V5 1.7.28(0.271/5/3) 2014-02-09 21:06 x86_64
OS: Windows 8.1  [Windows NT 6.3 build 9600](Win64)
Package: version 1.15.0-3 built 2014-02-25

XWin was started with the following command line:

X :0 -multiwindow

Initializing built-in extension Generic Event Extension
Initializing built-in extension SHAPE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SHM
Initializing built-in extension XInputExtension
Initializing built-in extension XTEST
Initializing built-in extension BIG-REQUESTS
Initializing built-in extension SYNC
Initializing built-in extension XKEYBOARD
Initializing built-in extension XC-MISC
Initializing built-in extension XINERAMA
Initializing built-in extension XFIXES
Initializing built-in extension XFree86-Bigfont
Initializing built-in extension RENDER
Initializing built-in extension RANDR
Initializing built-in extension COMPOSITE
Initializing built-in extension DAMAGE
Initializing built-in extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
Initializing built-in extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
Initializing built-in extension RECORD
Initializing built-in extension DPMS
Initializing built-in extension Present
Initializing built-in extension X-Resource
Initializing built-in extension GLX
(II) xorg.conf is not supported
(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
LoadPreferences: /home/Ethan/.XWinrc not found
LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw installed, allowing ShadowDD
winDetectSupportedEngines - Windows NT, allowing PrimaryDD
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 0000001f
winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 1920 height: 1080 depth: 32
winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff BPRGB 8 d 24 bpp 32
winInitMultiWindowWM - Calling pthread_mutex_lock ()
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - Calling pthread_mutex_lock ()
MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in the kernel
glWinSelectGLimplementation: Loaded 'cygnativeGLthunk.dll'
GL_VERSION:     4.2.0 - Build 10.18.10.3379
GL_VENDOR:      Intel
GL_RENDERER:    Intel(R) HD Graphics 4400
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_multisample and GLX_SGIS_multisample
(II) 67 pixel formats reported by wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
(II) AIGLX: Set GLX version to 1.4
(II) 22 fbConfigs
(II) GLX: Initialized Win32 native WGL GL provider for screen 0
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/TTF/, removing from list!
[dix] Could not init font path element /usr/share/fonts/OTF/, removing from list!
winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 960 540
(--) 5 mouse buttons found
(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
(--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000409" (00000409) "US", type 4
(--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA)"
(--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
winBlockHandler - pthread_mutex_unlock()
winInitMultiWindowWM - pthread_mutex_lock () returned.
winInitMultiWindowWM - pthread_mutex_unlock () returned.
winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - pthread_mutex_lock () returned.
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - pthread_mutex_unlock () returned.
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
winInitMultiWindowWM - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
/usr/bin/xterm.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXpm-4.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

For some reason, all of them seem to complain about not being able to find `cygXmu-6.dll` and `cygXpm-4.dll`, even though both libraries are installed.